# Beckhoff Twincat 3.1 (TC3 TE2000 HMI) Howto call methods in UserControl using Parameters

Tags: plc, twincat

HI I've build a usercontrol in the TE2000 HMI environment with a button. Now I would like to call a PLC method from the instantiated usercontrol. All required data (including methods, which are enabled for the HMI by using the pragma) are coupled to usercontrol instance parameter using a DUT.

As long as I call the method explicit, it works like a charm. For example:

```
TcHmi.Symbol.readEx2("%s%factoryPLC.MAIN.fbRobot::fbEM01_Robot::fbCM04_Compressor::M_Start%/s%", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

However when calling the appropriate parameter so I can have multiple instances, it does not work:

```
TcHmi.Symbol.readEx2("%pp%cmData::M_Start%/pp%", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

This results in the following error:

`Object { error: 2030, value: undefined, details: {…} } ​ details: Object { code: 2030, message: "E_SYMBOL_INVALID_PATH", reason: '%pp%UserControl1_8::cmData::M_Start%/pp%: Failed to read value by path because the token: "M_Start" does not exist below path: "UserControl1_8::cmData" in current value.', … }`

Now the [Infosys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/te2000_tc3_hmi_engineering/10740006667.html&id=)  manual mentions: "Methods must always be called explicitly and *cannot be used as a control attribute*. Note that calling a method from the HMI results in the execution of PLC code."

The italic part is unclear to me; does it mean I cannot call a method as a parameter? Is there a workaround? I cannot believe it would be impossible to call a method indirectly from a usercontrol?

Thanks in advance,
Wouter

Answer (score 0):

For future reference,

I've got an answer from Beckhoff Support:

Calling methods and properties is only possible when you do this explicitly by using the code you use.

UserControls create some layer between symbol and the internal representation of the parameter in the instantiated user control. They also manage implicitly writing to and from the linked symbol. They don't support methods and properties.

A possible work-around is:
Pass your symbol as a string "%s%factoryPLC.MAIN.fbRobot::fbEM01_Robot::fbCM04_Compressor%/s%" to the parameter of the user control.Inside your user control call explicitly "%Parameter::M_Start%/s%"
This way you still have the re-usability of a user control which can be linked with the symbol you wish.

Please note this is a work-around  which will function. ** Currently the requested functionality is not supported by the platform.